# gradle dependency on another non sub-project

Tags: dependencies, gradle

I have two gradle projects A and B. A depends on B, but this is not a multi project build (B is just a shared service in another project).

Is there a way to express in gradle that A is dependent on B, even though B lives in a different path in the repository? My repository looks like:

```
projects
   A/
      build.gradle
   B/
      build.gradle
```

I would prefer that A always builds B from source rather than depending on a specific binary version.

Answer (score 0):

If both A and B are already in the same parent directory, you can convert them to a multi-module build by adding a settings.gradle script in the parent that includes both projects. It shouldn't affect anything in the projects themselves, unless you use `project.path` in the scripts. And it allows you to setup compile-time dependencies between both projects.

Comment: Right I thought about doing that, but I don't think this really is a multi module project. Image I had projects A and C that are unrelated, but they both depend on B - should they all be in one multi module project?

Comment: A and B could form one multi-project build, and C and B another one. It would be more common to share B as a binary though, because if A and C are unrelated, you may not want to tie them together by having to depend on the latest source code revision of B all the time.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for the comment. We're still trying to figure out if we want to depend on the latest source or a binary, but this gives us some options.